# Is it possible to minimize by mouse click?

Tags: mouse, minimize, click-policy

Is it possible to minimize or close any application or browser by mouse click.

If I click any icon on launcher then the application opens but if I click on the same icon then it does not get close or minimize.

I need to go to the minimize or close button for the same.

Please let me know.

Comment: You can right click and choose close.

Comment: is there any option to minimize

Comment: Not by using default unity packages. `status-by-design` they say. :( [have a look at this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ayatana-design/+bug/733349)